# testng run all test classes in one thread

Tags: java, testng

I have a project with tests, which runs using TestNG and maven. TestNG runs test classes in several threads, what is not acceptable to me, I want to run all test classes in one thread.
I know that it is possible to run all test methods inside of the specified test class in one thread, but how to run all test methods in all test classes in one thread? Is there any simple way to do it without depending each test class to previous?

I've tried to configure maven surefire plugin like that, but it does'n work.

```html
<configuration>
  <threadCount>1</threadCount>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

TestNG does not run in parallel by default, you must have enabled the parallel mode somewhere, probably in the `<suite>` tag of your testng.xml.

Answer (score 1):

I may be wrong in understanding your situation. Ideally if different tests you have can't be run in parallel then you certainly have issues with the way tests are written. Any test should not be dependent on any other test ideally and they should be capable of being run in parallel. If they can't be run in parallel then probably you will like to refactor your tests so that no test is dependent on any other test.

Comment: Yes, this is correct for simple unit tests. And it works for unit tests well. But I have separate project for the integration tests, and these tests use common database. And one tests sometimes brokes another tests because of unexpected database data.

Comment: Actually what I was trying to say holds true for integration tests as well. Each of your integration tests should rely on non-shared data.

Comment: It depends on situation. For example I want to retrieve first record from the table with sorting by any field, for example, get one record with the oldest modification date. Such test will check that sorting works. But other integration tests could use this table in parallel thread, and, for example, clean it up or insert something new.

Comment: For these cases you can have different tables for different integration tests as anyway the data in tables would be sample data you will be testing with.